# REGEX and PHP, cant not matches multiple expressions

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get all the `<img>`  on a html page. I am using the following code:

```
$pattern = '/<im\w+\s+[^>]*>/';
preg_match($pattern, $html, $matches);
```

Some how this works but `$matches` array is only hodling the latest occurence of my selection (i was expeting to have as many index in that array as i have instances of the matched selection)

Am i doing something worng ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but $matches is then a 2 level array, so to acces value i have to do something like $matches[0][*] is this normal ?

Comment: @silkAdmin: Yes, it is. It's the way preg_match_all works. Have a look at the doc, see edited answer.